# How to display menu in android using code?

Tags: java, android, menu

I am running my android app on my samsung galaxy s2 phone. The phone has a physical menu button, and if I click it, I get a menu overlap that has 1 option that says by default "Settings". Some phones don't have the physical menu button. I made a button in the app for this purpose, to show the menu.

However I don't know how to show the menu using java code.

Does anyone know how do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if devices without a physical button have the "3 dots" in the actionbar instead?

Comment: But how can I reveal the menu using code? That is my question. This needs to support android 2.2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `openOptionsMenu();` and it will programmatically open the options menu.

I suppose you can't do this in `onCreate`, or other methods similar to this where the options menu has not yet been created.

[*reference to Android's official documentation.*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)

Comment: Does not work in Lollypop. Does not crash either,  it just does nothing.